# Unable to retrieve private release asset from Github using ansible

Tags: github, ansible, github-api

I'm trying to automatically download a release asset using ansible, but I receive a 400 "Invalid Argument error":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error>
        <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>
        Only one auth mechanism allowed;
        only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter
        or the Authorization header should be specified
    </Message>
    <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>Basic XXX</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>XXXX</RequestId>
    <HostId>XXXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have found a [corresponding issue](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/967) on GitHub, but I can't implement the solution using ansible without writing a custom script. My curremt code is:

```
- name: Download build asset
  uri:
    url: "{{ asset_url }}"
    user: "{{ github_username }}"
    password: "{{ github_token }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    headers:
      Accept: application/octet-stream
```

I have also tried passing no headers and using the token in the url

```
- name: Download build asset
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ TOKEN }}:@api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/assets/{{ ASSET_ID }}"
    headers:
      Accept: application/octet-stream
```

But then I receive an error 404 "Not found" Error (presumably because the authentication did not work (private URL parameters replaced as ):

```
fatal: [XXX]: FAILED! => changed=false
  access_control_allow_origin: '*'
  access_control_expose_headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
  connection: close
  content: '{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-asset"}'
  content_length: '110'
  content_security_policy: default-src 'none'
  content_type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  date: Wed, 18 Nov 2020 15:45:42 GMT
  elapsed: 0
  json:
    documentation_url: https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-asset
    message: Not Found
  msg: 'Status code was 404 and not [200]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found'
  redirected: false
  referrer_policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
  server: GitHub.com
  status: 404
  strict_transport_security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
  url: https://<TOKEN>@api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/assets/28089234
  vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
  x_content_type_options: nosniff
  x_frame_options: deny
  x_github_media_type: unknown
  x_github_request_id: CC26:2942:15E1154:1948AE9:5FB541A6
  x_ratelimit_limit: '60'
  x_ratelimit_remaining: '58'
  x_ratelimit_reset: '1605717756'
  x_ratelimit_used: '2'
  x_xss_protection: 1; mode=block
```

This only happens for release assets, other api calls work just fine using the basic auth method. It also works fine with the same request using curl or postman. Scopes for the Personal Access Token I use are:

- repo (full access)
- workflow
- write:packages

  - read:packages

---

### Update

For now sending the request using curl works, but I would prefer using the uri module:

```
name: Download build asset
  shell: >
    curl -J -L -H "Accept: application/octet-stream"
    "https://{{ TOKEN }}@api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/releases/assets/{{ ASSET_ID }}"
    --output "/tmp/asset.tar.gz"
```

Comment: (a) it's very suspicious that your URL is not a URL (b) the error message seems pretty clear that you cannot use that `Accept` header with their API (c) the issue you linked to doesn't use `/releases/<ID>` [it uses `/releases/assets/<ID>`](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/967#issuecomment-625835047)

Comment: Sorry about that. The malformed URL was due to me removing private information. I'm 90% sure I sent the correct URL, although testing now I'm getting a 404 response (Presumably because the auth didnt work).

For now I'm sending the Request with curl, but I find the command much less readable

Comment: But, as I said, your playbook uses `/releases/<ID>` and the working curl uses the `/releases/assets/{{ ASSET_ID }}`, so update your question with the error produced when you use the right URL in the `uri:` module

Comment: Did I not? I just rechecked and I'm still getting a 404 error when using the given URL. I checked the debug output and its definitely the correct URL

Comment: You have, at least according to the code you pasted, again used a different URL in ansible than in curl -- the ansible `url:` contains a `:` after the `TOKEN }}`; I think this will be my last comment on this thread; good luck